# String's split or charAt

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash

I'm writing a casino game in which I need to encrypt all the data I pass through sockets, so I want as much performance as I can get, because encryption and decryption may happen quite a lot, and I don't want it to be laggy.

My question is which is faster performance-wise when you have a `String` and you want to get it's characters at high speed, `myString.charAt(i)` or having `var a:Array = myString.split('');` and then getting them like this `a[i];`

My `for` cycle may run 60-100 times or more. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

benbjo's advice is a solid one. If performance is *really* a concern, the best test case is the situation where you're actually going to use your code, not least because of garbage collection and the JIT'er making things unpredictable in terms of the *actual* performance.

That said, the `charAt` approach in general will be (20-50%) faster than `split()`. Memory-wise there shouldn't be much of a difference - both approaches are creating a new string per character. In addition to that, the `split()` obviously also creates an additional array.

A comparison of these two methods:

charAt:

```
var s:String = "";
for (var j:int = 0; j < len; j++)
{
    // The string concat seems to be enough to confuse the JIT compiler.
    s += v.charAt(j);
}
```

split:

```
var s:String = "";
var arr:Array = v.split("");
for (var j:int = 0; j < len; j++)
{
    // The string concat seems to be enough to confuse the JIT compiler.
    // Using just arr[j] seems to be unfairly optimized.
    s += arr[j];
}
```

The relevant compiled ABC byte code is predictably identical between the two, except the call to split, and the array access vs. calling `charAt()`. In other words, no crazy optimization stunts by the ASC compiler (those are rare anyway).

10 runs, 1000 iterations each of the above code, release build on release player:

```
FP WIN 11,5,502,110           :  #Runs  #Iter           Avg           Min           Max          Iter
charAt :: string length: 50   :     10   1000        9.0 ms          6 ms         10 ms     0.0090 ms
split  :: string length: 50   :     10   1000       13.0 ms          8 ms         19 ms     0.0130 ms
charAt :: string length: 500  :     10   1000       68.5 ms         58 ms         97 ms     0.0685 ms
split  :: string length: 500  :     10   1000      100.5 ms         86 ms        136 ms     0.1005 ms
charAt :: string length: 1000 :     10   1000      149.3 ms        119 ms        202 ms     0.1493 ms
split  :: string length: 1000 :     10   1000      201.2 ms        162 ms        261 ms     0.2012 ms
charAt :: string length: 2000 :     10   1000      283.8 ms        230 ms        378 ms     0.2838 ms
split  :: string length: 2000 :     10   1000      326.9 ms        307 ms        423 ms     0.3269 ms
charAt :: string length: 4000 :     10   1000      575.8 ms        475 ms        752 ms     0.5758 ms
split  :: string length: 4000 :     10   1000      665.0 ms        609 ms        888 ms     0.6650 ms
charAt :: string length: 5000 :     10   1000      650.9 ms        581 ms        915 ms     0.6509 ms
split  :: string length: 5000 :     10   1000      863.4 ms        769 ms       1219 ms     0.8634 ms
charAt :: string length: 10000:     10   1000     1300.5 ms       1155 ms       1707 ms     1.3005 ms
split  :: string length: 10000:     10   1000     1797.3 ms       1534 ms       2461 ms     1.7973 ms
```

Avg = average time for each run (of 1000 iterations)

Min = minimum time for a single run

Max = maximum time for a single run

Iter = average time for a single iteration.

The variance between runs is fairly large, likely due to garbage collection happening during some of the runs. But the result is consistently in favour of `charAt()`. Making the `split()` call once before each run rather than redoing it in each iteration doesn't make much difference. In other words, the difference in performance really does lie in accessing the array being slower than calling `charAt()`. It's not the *huge* difference, however, that you'll get from, say, using `indexOf` instead of a regex for searching a string.

In general, although it's not a hard-and-fast rule, the most obvious approach to simple tasks like string manipulation will likely be the faster one. The FlashPlayer team spent a lot of time optimizing string manipulation, concatenation etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could always test yourself to see what is more effective in your situation and if it matters at all by using getTimer before and after your code has executed:

```
var testTime:int;
var before:int = getTimer();

//You code here

testTime = getTimer() - before;
trace(testTime);
```

So basically, you input your two algorithms and check how much time the take to execute.

EDIT: Apocalyptic0n3 is naturally right. Best use new Date.time() instead of getTimer() as it is more accurate in case of freeze.

Comment: You're right but memory also matters here :) not only time :)

Comment: Probably best to not use `getTimer()` for things like this. The timer is, as far as I know, reliant on the app. If the app freezes, so does the Timer. I've often seen `startTime - getTimer()` return 0 despite the process visibly taking 5-10 seconds. You're better off using `new Date().time` instead, as that should always be accurate and has nothing at all to do with the app.

Comment: @wvxvw Odd. I've had nothing but bad results when benchmarking with it. For that reason, I go with `var start = new Date().time; /*operation goes here*/ trace(new Date().time - start);` whenever I do benchmarking now.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is just too much for a comment.

First of all, it is hard to tell what you are trying to do and why do you need to compare these things, but as I've already said. If you are looking into serialization - learn to use the built-in serialization. I've seen it happen so many times when someone re-invented the wheel and it was *orders of magnitude* worse in *every possible respect*, then the built-in one. The only excuse to do this really is if you are learning how things work.

Of course, if you are planning on processing hundreds of thousands of files - you could write in C and use a native extension in AIR or some such, and that would definitely win.

Now, if you are wondering about the fastest way to process string data, that would be neither of our choices. The fastest would be to load it into domain's memory and to use so called "Alchemy opcodes" to access the bytes of data. This will be very fast if strings use 8-bits encoding, and not so fast, if they use Unicode. Obviously, this will also affect your tests if you were to test what you suggested before.

Second best option: a vector made of integers, which are char-codes. These are better optimizied and use different memory allocation model.

Third fastest might be `ByteArray` or `BitmapData`.

**BUT** this is all absolutely not important if you do something silly in serialization. And in order to do that properly you really need a good strategy, you need to understand information theory on good level to make predictions about how this or other way of *compressing* the data will reduce the size, or will be easier or faster implemented and so on. There are a lot of good examples of bad decisions in this field which become popular. Base64 encoding, XML and JSON formats are examples of unthoughtful design which stuck.

When it comes to Flash, the choice is absolutely obvious, in every respect AMF is better then just any option you may have on the table. You need to have a very advanced understanding of what you are doing, to roll your own and to make it better.

PS. One more note: if you don't want to make additional allocations with `charAt` - you can use `substr` or `substring`, because these don't cause reallocations, but will prevent the source string from being deallocated until the subtracted string lives.

Comment: The only thing that helps from your answer is the P.S. part :) Thanks anyway. I never mentioned serialization. It's for security reasons. I don't even compare the strings, I just scramble it's characters.